# can i find the number of data points in a parquet file based on file size and schema structure

Tags: parquet

I have a list of parquet files in s3 and i need to find the number of data points stored in it (even approximate count would be good). I know the schema and size of the file.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `ParquetFile` you can inspect the meta data of a parquet file without having to read the actual data:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
file = pq.ParquetFile("s3://...")
file.metadata.num_rows
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have many such files all following same schema, is there a way to find the number of rows by knowing the file size, since 
`file = pq.ParquetFile("s3://...")` will result in reading the files one by one.

Comment: I do understand that we have FileMetaData,rowgroup,column chunk, page header and finally page with encoded data. but when the encoding, compression and schema is known will it be possible to get a approximate estimation of number of rows for a flat schema based parquet file based on file size.

Comment: You won't be able to get a definite answer because the performance of the compression algorithm depends on the values of your data. For example if all the values are the same, you get very good compression ratio. Also small files with few records in parquet (or small row groups) don't have good performance. Because they have a big meta data overhead.  The best you can do is open a few files metadata, get the number of record and do a basic linear regression between file size and number of records.